# Is it better to use Vue.js storefront as a frontend for magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, frontend, security, vuejs

We have to lunch a new store and planning to use Vue.js storefront on frontend.

-> Will it be feasible easily - data will be interchanged using APIs

-> Would there be any security issues ?

-> Any other factor that can effect ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your questions

> Will it be feasible easily - data will be interchanged using APIs

Magento 2.3 has been written to support this type integration.

> Would there be any security issues ?

Same security issues as standard magento installation

> Any other factor that can effect ?

Compatibility with other components or extensions. For example which payment methods are supported by this theme / integration.

Comment: thanks for reply. In last point, you mean the payment methods that are supported in vue.js storefront should be used in magento 2 backend only to avoid hustle ?

Comment: I think you might need two versions of a payment extension. One for front one for back. Maybe see what docs / devs of vue storefront have to say.